# One Loop with 2x ArrayList

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist

I have 2 ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> list1  
ArrayList<String> list2
```

I try to use 2 ArrayList in one loop. Example.

```
for(LatLng a : list1 [i dont know what put here] String b : list2)
{

Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(a, b));

}
```

what i should do ?

Comment: Are they bound by the same index? (i.e. the first position on list1 is paired with the first position in list2), if so just use a regular loop..

for(int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
    list1.get(i).blablabla
    list2.get(i).blablabla

Comment: Can you be more precise? a bi dimensional array doesn't look like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an enhanced for loop over 2 lists at once, the only option is to use a normal for loop:

```
//Assuming list1 and list2 are identical sizes:
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    LatLng latLng = list1.get(i);
    String s = list2.get(i);
    //Do something with them
}
```

If you REALLY want to do it in 1 loop, you might consider making a combination object:

```
public class CombinationObject{

    private LatLng latLng;
    private String string;

    //GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

Then you can add your elements to a list of `CombinationObject` : `List<CombinationObject> list;` and loop just over that singular list.

```
for (CombinationObject co : list){
    LatLng latLng = co.getLatLng();
    String s = co.getString();
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: size is identical so i use 1st answer, but this loop doing runs from the last element of the array, should runs from the first, I would like to work in the reverse order

Comment: use `Collections.reverse(list)` to reverse the order. Or add entries in reverse order, or create your own list implementation. You didn't specify the reverse order in your question...

Comment: i did not specify this in my question because when i use 1 Arraylist is good, from 1 to 10, but when i use 2 Arraylist, it is works reverse from 10 to 1

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I think what you are trying to achieve is obtaining the value from each ArrayList at corresponding indices? If so you can achieve it in this way:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> list1;  
ArrayList<String> list2;

if(list1.size() != list2.size()){
    Log.e("Arrays are not of the same size!");
}
else{
    for(int i = 0; i<list1.size(); i++){
        String s = list1.get(i).toString() + " : " + list2.get(i).toString(); 
        Log.d("Response", s);
    }
}
```